# Extract information from an official and community indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I would like to create alerts on TradingView. I usually use MQL5 and MT5 but the indicators I want to use are not available on MT5...

The list of values I would like to retrieve for my alert :

- McGinley Dynamic (natively available)
- Strength meter (community script with private source code)

I don't want to retrieve the codes of these indicators, but their values for, say, the last candle closed. Can anyone help me?

I've read the official documentation, but I can't find what I'm looking for.